# How erase extra black on drop down menu

Tags: html, css

sorry for the poor nesting
how can i get rid of the extra black that is created by this code.
If you need a link a to the site comment and ill do a quick ftp.
The black is showing up in the drop down menu.
it appeared as I was trying to center the menu.
//this is html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
    <title>BHSS Solar Racing</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <div>Bloomington High School South</div>
        <div>Solar Racing Team</div>
    </p>
    <p>
        <div>Helionauts</div>
    </p>
   <!--Team-->
    <p>
        <div>
        </div> 
    </p>
    <!--Sponsors-->
    <p>
        <div>
        </div>
    </p>
    <!--History-->
    <p>
        <div>
        </div>
    </p>
    <!--Vehicles-->
    <p>
        <div>
        </div>
    </p>
    <!--Donate-->
    <p>
        <nav>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Donate</a>
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sponsorship Perks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Payment Information</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

//this is css code

```
    nav ul ul {
display: none;
    }

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
    nav ul {
background: #000000; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #000000 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #000000 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%,#000000 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 0px;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
    left:640px;
display: inline-table;
    }
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
    nav ul li {
float: left;
    }
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
    nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;
}
     nav ul ul {
background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: relative; top: 100%;
    left:0px;
    }
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
    nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 15px 40px;
        color: #fff;
    }   
        nav ul ul li a:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
        }

    nav ul ul ul {
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: Yeah one more second.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=3t4Gyg3xQp

Comment: Are you referring to the black space that shows when you are hovering over a menu item?

Comment: Yes, I am referreing to that.

Comment: As an aside, I would highly recommend that you use CSS classes. CSS can become a real pain when you have so many nested elements without classes or ids

Comment: Yeah, true I will try to use them in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that since your submenus are nested within your main menu, any time your submenu is shown, the parent menu has to expand to make room for the submenu. This expansion is being illustrated by the extra black space that appears.

The solution here is to remove the background from your top most `ul` and instead apply it to its direct children `li`.

I've replaced your `nav ul` set of CSS rules with the following:

```
nav > ul > li {
    background: #000000;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #000000 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #000000 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #000000 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
nav ul {
    padding: 0 20px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    left:640px;
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Notice that any rules regarding the background or border have been moved to the `li`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ginovva320/8fypm/)